# value="#{detailCtr.montants.get(0)}": java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I want to recuperatete data from database that depends on ID of the same table witch is recuperated by another function with some conditions;

here is my code , but it doesn't work ,i don't know how to solve it :(

```
    @Override 
public List<Float> findMontantByIdDetail(BigDecimal numCaisCais, int   codDevDev)
{




        System.out.println("Debut Fonction  findMontantByIdDetail");

        DetailCaisse detail=new DetailCaisse();
        detail=findElementById( numCaisCais,  codDevDev);
        System.out.println(detail);

        List<Float> montants=new ArrayList<Float>() ;

        montants.add(detail.getMontToteDsc() );
        montants.add(detail.getMontTotsDsc() );

        System.out.println(montants.get(0) );
        System.out.println(montants.get(1));


        return montants;
}
```

### page.xhtml

```
        <h:outputText>Code Devise</h:outputText>
        <p:inputText value="#{detailCtr.codDevDev}" />
        <h:outputText>code Caisse</h:outputText>
        <p:inputText value="#{detailCtr.numCaisCais}" />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{detailCtr.findMontant()}"
                update="cc">

            </h:commandButton>

            <p:dataTable value="#{detailCtr.findMontant()}" var="detail"
                style="width:50px" id="crsvente">

                <p:column headerText="Montant total entrée" style="width:150px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{detailCtr.montants.get(0)}" id="cc" />

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Montant total Sortie" style="width:150px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{detailCtr.montants.get(1)}" id="cc" />

                </p:column>
```

### the error is :

```
 /pages/gestionCaisse/getMontant.xhtml @32,68 value="#{detailCtr.montants.get(0)}": java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

can you help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it, I will put the solution  :)

### findElementById

```
@Override
public DetailCaisse findElementById(BigDecimal numCaisCais, int codDevDev) {

    Connection conn = null;

    String sql = "select   d.num_dsc_dsc ,  d.mont_tote_dsc , d.mont_tots_dsc from DETAIL_CAISSE d ,Devise dev,  Caisse c where d.num_cais_cais=c.num_cais_cais  and d.cod_dev_dev= dev.cod_dev_dev and c.num_cais_cais=? and dev.cod_dev_dev=?";

    DetailCaisse detail = new DetailCaisse();

    try {

        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setBigDecimal(1, numCaisCais);
        ps.setInt(2, codDevDev);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            detail.setNumDscDsc(rs.getBigDecimal("num_dsc_dsc"));
            detail.setMontToteDsc(rs.getFloat("mont_tote_dsc"));
            detail.setMontTotsDsc(rs.getFloat("mont_tots_dsc"));

        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }

    }

    return detail;
}
```

### findMontantByIdDetail

```
@Override
public List<Float> findMontantByIdDetail(BigDecimal numCaisCais,
        int codDevDev) {

    DetailCaisse detail = new DetailCaisse();
    detail = findElementById(numCaisCais, codDevDev);
    System.out.println(detail);

    List<Float> montants = new ArrayList<Float>();

    montants.add(detail.getMontToteDsc());
    montants.add(detail.getMontTotsDsc());

    System.out.println(montants);

    System.out.println(detail.getMontToteDsc() + ""
            + detail.getMontTotsDsc());
    return montants;
}
```

### Page.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">

        <h:outputText>Code Devise</h:outputText>
        <p:inputText value="#{detailCtr.codDevDev}" />
        <h:outputText>code Caisse</h:outputText>
        <p:inputText value="#{detailCtr.numCaisCais}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{detailCtr.findMontant()}"
            update="cc">

        </h:commandButton>

        <p:dataTable value="#{detailCtr.findMontant()}" var="detail"
            style="width:50px" id="crsvente">


            <p:column headerText="Montant" style="width:150px">
                <h:outputText value="#{detail}" id="cc" />

            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Good luck for you all :)